# CONTAINSTABLE Dynamic OR condition SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wonder how could I build a dynamically or condition with `CONTAINSTABLE`?

Having in count that any of chain0, chain1, chain2, could be empty, no matter the order. I want to do something like `(1 = 0) OR` ... in case for example the first is empty, but it doesn't work

For example

```
declare @chain NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' 
declare @chain0 NVARCHAR(100) = '(FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "cat") AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "dog"))' 
declare @chain1 NVARCHAR(100) = '(FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "parrot") AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "snake"))' 
declare @chain2 NVARCHAR(100) = '(FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "pig") AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "leon"))' 

IF @chain0 <> ''
BEGIN
    SELECT @chain = @chain + ' OR ' + @chain0
END

IF @chain1 <> ''
BEGIN
   SELECT @chain = @chain + ' OR ' + @chain1
END

IF @chain2 <> ''
BEGIN
   SELECT @chain = @chain + ' OR ' + @chain2
END

SELECT * 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(TableAnimals, Title, @chain, @LenguageID) AS CT
```

Comment: formsof is a fulltext term and containstable is a way of doing fuzzy searches. Both are rarely used which is why you have not gotten any responses.

Comment: Did you resolve it ?